# I have spin Android app in which I am facing problem in withdrawal

Tags: android, android-studio, web-applications

I have spin app in which 100 points = 1 rupees is set but when I withdrawal it's become 1points = 1rs can any developer help me I have source code and all stuff please help me

Comment: Any developer who can help

Comment: share your source code then i will help you